# Let $\{b_n\}$ be a sequence with limit $\beta$. Show that if $B$ is an upper bound for $\{b_n\}$, then $\beta \leq B$.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis

Let $\{b_n\}$ be a sequence with limit $\beta$. Show that if $B$ is an upper bound  for $\{b_n\}$, then $\beta \leq B$.

What I have:

Assume that $\beta>B$, so $\beta-B>0$. Since $\{b_n\}$ converges to $\beta$ we know that there exists $N\in \mathbb{B}$ such that $|b_n-\beta|<\beta -B$ for all $n\geq N$.

How can I obtain a contradiction?

Comment: ...and you found $b_n>B$

Answer (score 2):

You found $|b_n-\beta|<\beta-B$. Writing this in expanded form gives $-\beta+B<b_n-\beta<\beta-B$. We add $\beta$ to both sides giving $B<b_n$.

Answer (score 1):

Remember $ \lvert b_n-\beta\rvert=\max\{b_n-\beta,\beta-b_n\} $ so the inequality $\lvert b_n-\beta\rvert <\beta-B$ implies $\beta-b_n<\beta-B$, which implies $b_n>B$, so that $B$ wouldn't be an upper bound for $b_n$.

Answer (score 0):

Assume that $ \beta >B$. Since $ \lbrace b_{n}\rbrace $ converges to $ \beta $, there exists $ N\in \mathbb{N} $ such that for each $ n\geq N $, $ \vert b_{n}-\beta \vert <\beta -B $. Then $ -(\beta -B)<b_{n}-\beta $ for each $ n\geq N $ and hence $ B<b_{n} $ for each $ n\geq N $. This is a contradiction with the fact that $ B $ is an upper bound. Therefore $ \beta \leq B $. $ \square $